# Binding datasource to Kendo Grid where some field may not be present in JSON

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid and the data is bound with results from a webApi. Below is a snapshot of the code. This is used to render the Kendo Grid. Now in the JSON result there could be cases where the field 'nominalVoltage' will not be there. In other words some results may return the field, some may not. In case the field is not returned the code fails. I will get error like field is undefined.
Can this be handled anyway while loading Kendo grid controls?

```
$scope.columns = [{
    field: 'businessCode',
    title: 'Business Code',
    width: '120px',
}, {
    field: 'nominalVoltage',
    title: 'Nominal Voltage',
    width: '120px'
}];

var options = {
    dataSource: {
        data: data
    },
    width: '100%',
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    dataBinding: function (e) {
        var pageSizes = e.sender.dataSource.pageSize() || 20;
    },
    pageable: {
        pageSize: pageSize,
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200],
        refresh: true
    },
    columns: $scope.columns
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a conditional [`template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) attribute on the grid column which requires validation:

```
field: 'nominalVoltage',
title: 'Nominal Voltage',
width: '120px',
template: "#if(nominalVoltage) {#:nominalVoltage#} else{'Oops nothing found'}#"
```

Or the template as a function,

```
template: validateNominalVoltage

function validateNominalVoltage(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.nominalVoltage ? dataItem.nominalVoltage : 'Oops nothing found';
}
```

Usually this method is used to modify how data is being displayed i.e. bolding content, using an external HTML template but in your case this will work fine for checking if the `nominalVoltage` attribute contains a value before displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `schema` for your data.

```
schema: {
    model: {
        businessCode: { type: "string" },
        nominalVoltage: { type: "number" },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define template like below

```
//field: 'nominalVoltage', // do not include it
template: function(data) {
  return data.nominalVoltage ? data.nominalVoltage : "";
},
title: 'Nominal Voltage',
width: '120px'
```